# rhombus shape igraph node

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to use the rhombus geometric shape as a node in a graph using igraph. I have found shapes like circle, triangle, rectangle but I didn't find rhombus. The rhombus should look similar to the rhombus obtained in a plot with pch = 18.

Does anyone have an example of working code for rhombus shape?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the package documentation, you have to define a custom shape.
The code below follows the help page `?igraph::shapes` example for the `"triangle"` custom shape. The main difference is in the definition of `stars`, in function `myrhombus`.

```
library(igraph)

myrhombus <- function(coords, v = NULL, params) {
  vertex.color <- params("vertex", "color")
  if (length(vertex.color) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
    vertex.color <- vertex.color[v]
  }
  vertex.size <- 1/200 * params("vertex", "size")
  if (length(vertex.size) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
    vertex.size <- vertex.size[v]
  }

  symbols(x = coords[, 1], y = coords[, 2], bg = vertex.color,
          stars = cbind(1.2*vertex.size, vertex.size, 1.2*vertex.size, vertex.size),
          add = TRUE, inches = FALSE)
}
# clips as a circle
add_shape("rhombus", clip = shapes("circle")$clip,
          plot = myrhombus)


g <- graph.ring(10, dir = FALSE)

plot(g, vertex.shape = "rhombus", vertex.color = rainbow(vcount(g)),
     vertex.size = rep(30, vcount(g)))
```

[image]